# NullReferenceException on App.Current.MainPage

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses push notifications. For some reason, the following line:

```
(App.Current.MainPage as MainPage)?.AddMessage(body);
```

that is called from Android native `OnMessageReceived()`, throws `NullReferenceException`.

Why can this happen? Isn't `App.Current` to be accessible from the platform-specific project?

Edit:

Here is the full `OnMessageReceived()` code:

```
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        string messageBody;

        if (message.GetNotification() != null)
        {
            messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;
        }

        // NOTE: test messages sent via the Azure portal will be received here
        else
        {
            messageBody = message.Data.Values.First();
        }

        // convert the incoming message to a local notification
        SendLocalNotification(messageBody);

        // send the incoming message directly to the MainPage
        SendMessageToMainPage(messageBody);
    }
```

Comment: I think it matters if it is called before or after `LoadApplication()`.

Comment: @Cfun As the app was running on the background, I believe the LoadApplication() had already been called?

Comment: I think so, could you confirm exactly by debugging at that point which object is null? `App.Current` or `App.Current.MainPage` ?

Comment: @Cfun The problem is that I cannot debug it, as (according to the documentation) emulator cannot be configured to receive notifications. I believe only App.Current can be null, as I use ?. after App.Current.MainPage.

Comment: oh good to know about emulator, Have you tried with `(App.Current?.MainPage as MainPage)?.AddMessage(body);` ?

Comment: Could you show your complete codes of the native OnMessageReceived() ? If it still not work,you could try to use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send message to the MainPage.

Comment: @Cfun After using ?. no more NullReferenceException.But this does not fix the issue, as I do need to AddMessage().

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I added OnMessageReceived() code to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidShochet You could try to use `MessagingCenter` to send the message to the page which you want receive it.That way, you don't have to worry about whether `App.Current`is `null`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thanks, I will, if I don't succeed. But can't it be that I need to use InvokeOnMainThread()?

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I tried MessagingCenter, but it doesn't work. In AppDelegate, I have this method:         [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)

Inside I call completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);

MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "newCall");

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT This message is not called in MainPage.xaml.cs. Though when I sent the message from another page on the shared project, it is caught and handled.

Comment: I don't know if DidReceiveRemoteNotification() is called, and if not, why...

Comment: Is your issue on Android or ios?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Both. But for Android so far, I worked around the issue by placing my code into the App class instead of the MainPage. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`App.Current.MainPage` may contain any Page, not necessary your type `MainPage`, for example it could be `NavigationPage`. As the result of casting is `null` it is clear that it is of some other type.

Also it could happen that nothing is assigned to it.

Comment: But I do know that it is MainPage.             Page page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MainPageModel>();
            FreshNavigationContainer simpleNav = new FreshNavigationContainer(page);
            MainPage = simpleNav;

Comment: I really don't know how Fresh works (and don't want to know), but I can tell you 100% that it is not. Why don't you debug and check it. You will see that it is not as simply it can't be if you see the error.

Comment: interesting about fact about `as` good to know.

Comment: @DavidShochet maybe you can try `((MainPage) App.Current.MainPage)?.AddMessage(body);` if I understod well Ivan point it will throw an `InvalidCastException ` exception

Comment: @Ivan Ičin But it is App.Current that is null. When I use ?., no more NullReferenceException.As I mentioned above, there is no way to configure Firebase in emulator to debug.

Comment: @Cfun I cannot do your change, as App.Current.MainPage will throw the exception. App.Current is null.

Comment: You think the MainPage is deleted whn the app goes to the background (I don't know to be honest)?

Comment: @Cfun I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: @DavidShochet if App.Current is null, add some timer, possibly even Task.Delay will work. Probably sometimes it needs some time to initialize.

Comment: @IvanIčin Well, how will a delay help? The app should be running before the message is sent, even long before, not milliseconds...

Comment: @DavidShochet Generally there are two possible cases - either we don’t know something or we have some wrong assumptions. There is the third one - black magic, but this far it has never happened.